# where do i put images for icons in java (netbeans) and how do i link them to the code?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, embedded-resource, imageicon

I'm trying to make a Jframe class that has buttons with icons

```
 public ImageIcon Flag = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("resources/Flag.png"));
```

Gives me a null pointer exception

"C:\Users\Khalidi\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MineSweeper\resources\Flag.png"

Is the full directory to reach the image I want
I created the folder resources to house the images I need
Where should i place the images? And what line of code should i be writing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Put the resources folder in the src and use a `/` at the beginning of the path you're currently using using.

Comment: Additional references cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply place a folder resources to the folder with compiled classes and make ImageIcon like this.

```
public ImageIcon Flag = new ImageIcon("resources/Flag.png");
```

Comment: Though this answer will work from the IDE, it will no longer work once the app is packaged into a jar

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, I am still beginner. I only uses it without making jar package. May I ask you, why it wouldn't work, if i pack my app into a jar?

Comment: When you pass a string it to the `ImageIcon`, it will look for a file on the file system, starting at the working directory. In the IDE is the working directory is the Project Root. That's why this will work in the IDE. But once in a jar, it becomes a binary resource, that needs to accessed via URL. In the case of the OP's current file structure, the file may not even get put into the jar, unless you customize the IDE's build configuration. I normally put all my resources in the `src` somewhere and use the `Class.getResource("/path/to/resources/image.png");`...

Comment: Where `path` is directly in the `src`. The default build will put everything in the `src` into the class path. And you can access class path resources by obtaining the URL from `getResource`, as others have pointed out.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9866659/2587435) for some good reading

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I am sure, it will save a lot of time not only to me.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the package path with the same method.
for example, if my image is in org.nisheeth.resources package, it should be written as follows.

```
public ImageIcon flag = new ImageIcon(Test.class.getResource("/org/nisheeth/resource/Flag.png"));
```

Answer (score 3):

When you're loading your images using `getClass().getResource()`, the JVM in fact uses your CLASSPATH to load the resource (you should take a close look at [`Class#getResource(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)).

As a consequence, to have your resource available, you must push it to your project output folder (must be something like `target`, no ?).

Answer (score 3):

As you asked for conventions: using the **Maven** build infrastructure, you would have

- src/main/java - java packages
- src/main/resources - resources like your images
- src/main/resources/images/Flag.png - some resource (no convention)

In your created jar / .classes

- /images/Flag.png

  ```
  public ImageIcon Flag = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/Flag.png"));
  ```

Here, `Class.getResource()` uses a relative path to the package of the class; therefore, using an absolute path as above ("/...") is easiest.

Answer (score -1):

Create a package say ImgPack and paste all your images to this package and access all the images using

```
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\ImgPack\\<Imagename.extention>");
```