# getting null error when creating icon in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, icons, jlabel

I have the following package: projectname/src/main/java/net/is/lms/project/frames
In the frame folder there is a java class called testframe and an icon called icontest.png (it's 87x84px)

I have the following code snippet:

```
package net.is.lms.project.frames;

import javax.swing.*;

public class testframe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(530, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        String url = "src/main/java/net/is/lms/project/frames/icontest.png";
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);

        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setIcon(icon);
        frame.add(label);
    }
}
```

When I create the frame, no icon gets displayed

I tried different paths and also adding it like that:
URL url = testframe.class.getResource("/net/is/lms/project/frames/icontest.png");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment.

Have you tried to put the images in the `src/main/resources` folder and loading them like in this example: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236213/where-do-i-put-images-for%20%20-icons-in-java-netbeans-and-how-do-i-link-them-to-the)